# How do I create a div the size of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

Note that I'm **not** asking how to make a `div` the size of the "window" or "viewport" for which there are plenty of existing questions.

I have a web page of some height and width, and I'd like to add an empty, top-level div (i.e., not one containing the rest of the page) with a size exactly equal to the page's height and width. In practice, I also want it to be *at least* the size of the viewport.

I know I can do a one-time calculation of the height and width in JavaScript:

```
var height = Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight,
                      document.documentElement.clientHeight);
var width = Math.max(document.body.scrollWidth,
                     document.documentElement.clientWidth);
```

But this value can change based on images loading, or AJAX, or whatever other dynamic stuff is going on in the page. I'd like some way of locking the size of the div at the full page size so it resizes dynamically and on-demand.

I have tried something like the following:

```
function resetFakeBg() {
  // Need to reset the fake background to notice if the page shrank.
  fakeBg.style.height = 0;
  fakeBg.style.width = 0;
  // Get the full page size.
  var pageHeight = Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight,
                             document.documentElement.clientHeight);
  var pageWidth = Math.max(document.body.scrollWidth,
                            document.documentElement.clientWidth);
  // Reset the fake background to the full page size.
  fakeBg.style.height = pageHeight + 'px';
  fakeBg.style.width = pageWidth + 'px';
}

// Create the fake background element.
fakeBg = setFakeBgStyle(document.createElement('div'));
document.body.appendChild(fakeBg);
// Keep resizing the fake background every second.
size_checker_interval = setInterval(resetFakeBg, 1000);
```

## Limitations

This is for a Chrome extension, and I'd like to limit my modification of the page to adding this single `div`. This means that adding CSS to modify the height and width of the `html` and/or `body` tags is undesirable because it might have side-effects on the way the rest of the page is rendered.

In addition, I do not want to wrap the existing page in the `div` because that has the potential to break some websites. Imagine, for example, a site styled with the CSS selector `body > div`. I'd like my extension to break as few websites as possible.

## WHY OH WHY WOULD I NEED TO DO THIS?

Because some people like to hold their answers hostage until they're satisfied that I have a Really Good Reason™ for wanting to do this:

This is for an accessibility-focused Chrome extension that applies a CSS filter across an entire page. Recent versions of Chrome (>= 45) do not apply CSS filters to backgrounds specified on the `<html>` or `<body>` tag. As a result, I have chosen to work around this limitation by copying the page's background onto a div with a very negative `z-index` value, so that it can be affected by the page-wide CSS filter. For this strategy to work, the div needs to exactly imitate the way the page background would appear to a user—by being the exact size of the document (and no larger) and at least filling the viewport.

Comment: Why don't you use twitter bootstrap? I felt your requirement similar to a div having ```container-fluid class```

Comment: @RamkumarKR Reading about it, that class is for something "spanning the entire width of your viewport", which isn't what I'm after.

Comment: Im unsure where your problem is, to create a sticky footer for example you need to create a div wrapper that's takes up the entire viewport and wraps the content so if it is larger then it pushes the footer down. How is what you are trying to do any different? More specifics please, any code?

Comment: @MatthewRath The very first line of my question asserts that I am not asking for how to set something the size of a viewport. I am not trying to do anything like a sticky footer. What I am trying to do is different because I want something the size of the PAGE, not the VIEWPORT. These are distinct concepts.

Comment: This is unclear. What is a "page" on a website? If you are making a div the size of the page but not subject to anything else, you can set it to whatever size you need: what are you calculating? There is nothing in the page to calculate. If I've got the wrong end of the stick, please edit the question to say exactly what you are doing -- and probably why, because there may be a better way than you are currently envisaging.

Comment: Need more specifics, post the code and I'll help you out.

Comment: I'm betting you're trying to create some kind of overlay the size of the content on the page (and therefore scrollable with the page), in which case can you explain why you don't just insert a node into the DOM and have it wrap page content, then adjust the z-index to display on top of everything else, [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/72mt9knj/)? In this way it doesnt matter if the page content expands with AJAX requests or whatever the wrapper will expand with it.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I'm not sure how I could be any more clear about what I consider the page size than posting the JavaScript snippet I did. Perhaps you should consult the documentation on those functions?

Comment: @MatthewRath That's close to what I want to do, but I cannot wrap the page content because that could break some poorly written CSS selectors. Imagine the page did something dumb like style `body > div`. This wrapper would break that. As an extension author, I cannot enforce any kind of guidelines on websites, so I just have to deal with bad practices like that and try to make sure my extension does the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval()` is your best friend in cases like this where you want the `.height()` and `.width()` of an element to be asynchronously specified all the time to something that can be dynamicly altered by user input and DOM tree changes.  It is what I dub as a "page sniffer", and arguably, works better than `$(document).ready` if you are working in multiple languages (PHP, XML, JavaScript).

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/ojoevj1k/2/)

Comment: Your example doesn't quite represent the situation I'm describing, but my current solution already involves using `setInterval()`. I'm really hoping for a better way than to just periodically check the object and recalculate the size.

Answer (score -1):

You should get away with setting the width and height in the window resize function, you might wanna add it in a load function as well, when all data/images are loaded.

Comment: Window resize is triggered when the user resizes the window, not when something in the window changes.

Answer (score -1):

just add width=100%

e.g;-

Hello World

Answer (score -1):

I think you must do it like this:

```
...
<body>
<script>
function height()
{var height = Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight,
                      document.documentElement.clientHeight);}
function width()
{var width = Math.max(document.body.scrollWidth,
                     document.documentElement.clientWidth);}
</script>
<div height="height()" width="width()">
</div>
</body>
...
```

Comment: This does not work. Even if it did, it would not be able to respond to changes that reduce the page size because the page size would never actually be reduced lower than the size of the div.